# Grunt tasks stuck in endless loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-concat

Working on putting together a base `Gruntfile.js` for some upcoming projects. Starting in on a new computer so everything has been a fresh build. Installed Node and NPM using Homebrew, and then installed Grunt globally, as well as in my local directory.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "timespent-prototype",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "assemble": "0.4.37",
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

And here is my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
      vendor: {
       src: ['vendor/**/*.min.js'],
       dest: 'build/javascripts/library.js',
      }
    },

    // Takes your scss files and compiles them to css
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: {
          'build/stylesheets/application.css': 'app/stylesheets/application/index.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    // Assembles your templates into HTML files
    assemble: {
      options: {
        layoutdir: 'app/views/layouts/',
        partials: ['app/views/partials/*.hbs'],
        flatten: true,
        expand: true
      },
      pages: {
        src: ['app/views/**/*.hbs','!app/views/layouts/*.hbs','!app/views/partials/*.hbs'],
        dest: 'build/'
      }
    },

    wiredep: {
      task: {
        src: ['app/views/layouts/*.hbs']
      }
    },

    // Watches for file changes, runs the default task
    watch: {
      files: ['app/**/*'],
      tasks: ['default'],
      options: {
        // Start another live reload server on port 1337
        livereload: 1337,
      }
    }

  });

  // Load the plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('assemble');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wiredep');

  // Register the tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass','assemble']);
  grunt.registerTask('watch', ['watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('concat', ['concat']);
  grunt.registerTask('wiredep', ['wiredep']);
};
```

The problem that I am seeing is that with multiple tasks, here specifically with `wiredep` and `concat`, the task gets stuck in a loop and never ends. Running `grunt concat` with verbose outputs like this:

```
Registering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/jacksonlynch/projects/timespent-prototype/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/jacksonlynch/projects/timespent-prototype/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
+ concat

Running tasks: concat

Running "concat" task

Running "concat" task

Running "concat" task

Running "concat" task

Running "concat" task

Running "concat" task
```

Where `Running "concat" task` will continue to print until I stop it. As I am seeing this with multiple plugins and tasks this might be a problem with my installation of NPM or Grunt, but I'm having a very hard time debugging this. If anyone has run into this before, please let me know what helped!

Thanks!

---

Edit: in response to Alireza Ahmadi's comment, here is my file structure:

```
.
|
|_ app/
  |_ assets/
  |_ javascript/
  |_ stylesheets/
  |_ views/
|
|_ build/
  |_stylesheets/
  |_javascripts/
|
|_ vendor/
|_ bower.json
|_ Gruntfile.js
|_ package.json
```

Comment: Why destination of some tasks starts with `build` and destination of the concat task starts with `dist`? Can you share your folder structure with at least 2 level of depth?

Comment: Thanks for the response! That was just a poor copy and paste, the destination should always be `build`, I corrected that and added the file structure requested.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the last 2 lines of your `Gruntfile.js` you have redeclared the `concat` and `wiredep` tasks and when grunt tries to run your code, It stuck in an endless loop because concat refers to an undefined concat task, So you should remove these lines:

```
grunt.registerTask('concat', ['concat']);
grunt.registerTask('wiredep', ['wiredep']);
```

In general, When you define a task named `foobar` with `grunt.initConfig`, It's defined and does not need to registered using `registerTask` and it can be accessible by `grunt foobar` command.

Comment: This was the answer. Thanks Alireza! I did not realize that `initConfig` would also register a task for it. Thanks so much!

Comment: For me it was that I had my task named the same as the register config name